# Acer Aspire ES15 with Debian gets wifi connected but without internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, acer-aspire

What's up guys!

I have installed Debian stretch dualbooting with Windows 10 on Acer Aspire ES 15. This issue started when I logged in and tried to get internet connected using wireless but only wifi gets connected (without internet).

I am writing this question right now using wired connection and as I can see the issue might be with drivers but I am not being able to get things working by myself.

When I open Windows 10 wifi connection works normally.

As many helpers usually asks on wifi related issues, I ran wireless-info script and uploaded here: https://file.io/11fJO0.

Thanks for you help!

-- EDIT 03/11 --
ip route (output)

```
rodrigo@rodrigo-PC:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp1s0 proto static metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp1s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.101 metric 100
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you get the Wi-Fi connection up but are not be able to reach the hosts in the Internet?

Comment: Exacly! And this only happens when I connect through debian. When I switch to Windows it does work properly

Comment: Well, then I'm inclined to think you have a rounting/firewall issue rather than Wi-Fi driver issue. Let's check this: after the Wi-Fi interface goes up, fire up a terminal and issue here the `ip route` command. Could you please copy and pase it into your question? (There's no private information in the routing table, FWIW).

Comment: Thanks for your reply kostix!
I just edited my question with ip route output

Comment: This time I couldn't get wireless connected. This is getting pretty odd. I have entered ip route command using the same router but using wired connection

Comment: That's not too interesting, alas. Let me explain my idea better: you've told that your Wi-Fi interface goes up just okay but you're unable to connect to the Internet. So I wanted to know the two things: 1) the WLAN inerface gets assigned an IP address; 2) what's the state of the routing table afterwards. We'd then try to `ping` the Wi-Fi access point itself and also I'd be able to see whether the routing table looks OK in the terms of having a route to the Internet via the Wi-Fi access point. If these things would be OK, I'd speculate about possible firewall issues.

Comment: As of now, the information you provided is not very interesting: we already knew your wired connection works OK. So is it true that the WLAN interface actually gets up if you try to get connected through it (and not through the Ethernet (wired) interface)?

Comment: All-in-all, I'd recommend to post to [the `debian-users` mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/) (you don't have to be subscribed to it to post there) since problems like yours suppose longish roundtrips of extra questions and answers to them—badly fit for the SO format.